# DBT SNOWFLAKE : reference internal stage as source

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-stage

Is it possible to reference internal Snowflake stage in DBT source yml ?
I know this is possible with external stage using the module : https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables
But this does not work for internal stages.
This functionnality would enable to parse csv from stage directly in dbt, and access the metadata that come with snowflake stage.
Thanks for your help !